# F#: Iterating over a dictionary just returns itself?

Tags: collections, dictionary, f#, loops

```
let h = dict [(1, 2), (3, 4)]
Console.WriteLine(h.Count)
for i in h do
    Console.WriteLine(i)
```

gives me

```
1
[(1, 2), (3, 4)]
```

Two questions. Firstly, why does iterating over a dict give me back a sequence which only has 1 item, the dict itself? There is probably some logic behind this that will also affect other things I end up trying to iterate over. What does this mean for all the other Seq members exposed by dict (Any(), All(), Aggregate(), etc.)?

Secondly, is there a good way to iterate over and generally manipulate the key-value pairs in the dictionary, like in Python?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You used a comma where you need a semicolon.

```
[(1,2); (3,4)]
```

Commas for tuples, semicolons for list elements.  (The parens here are optional.)

If you want to iterate over key-value pairs in the dictionary, you can use

```
for KeyValue(k,v) in someDictionary do ...
```

which uses the [KeyValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340489.aspx) active pattern.

Comment: @Tomas - Flawless victory!  :)

Comment: damn damn damn, i knew it was something silly like that. Too much using using commas in other languages. Thanks =)