# How do you access items in a tuple that is a discriminated union?

Tags: f#

Say I declare a type like so:

```
type Kvp = Kvp of string * int
```

And I create an instance of it

```
let inst = Kvp("twelve", 12)
```

How do I get the first and second values from inst? Fst and snd don't work:

```
fst inst;;
stdin(81,5): error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type
    'a * 'b
but here has type
    Kvp
```

Comment: btw, I'm not sure what you are trying to do but there is a built-in KeyValue pair Active Pattern: [KVP1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7699346/f-iterating-over-a-dictionary-just-returns-itself/7699361#7699361/) and [KVP2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117302/how-to-convert-a-dictionary-into-a-sequence-in-f/1117320#1117320)

Answer (score 3):

As s952163 mentioned, pattern matching is what you want. However, the nice syntax is this

```
type Kvp = Kvp of string * int
let inst = Kvp("twelve", 12)

let (Kvp (str,i)) = inst 
// val str : string = "twelve"
// val i : int = 12
```

You can also use `_` to discard what you don't want:

```
let (Kvp (str,_)) = inst
```

[Here's the F# for fun and profit page on Single Case DUs](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/designing-with-types-single-case-dus/)

Answer (score 2):

Because a DU is not a tuple you get that error. But you can pattern match on a DU:

```
type Kvp = Kvp of string * int
let inst = Kvp("twelve", 12)

let (a,b) = 
    match inst with
    | Kvp(a,b) -> (a,b)
//val b : int = 12
//val a : string = "twelve"
```

And somewhere in the middle of [F# Fun](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/discriminated-unions/) there is an example of a matcher functions.